# Can't upload firmware on ESP32-WROOM-32UE with CP2102N

Tags: esp32, cp2102

I designed a custom ESP32 board with a CP2102N bridge (schematic attached). I'm using an ESP32-WROOM-32UE. My schematic is based on the ESP32-Devkitc-V4 board from Espressif (schematic attached). When I plug the board to my computer (with VCC connected to a 7.2V power supply), the CP2102N is correctly showing on the device manager. However, I didn't manage to upload any code to my ESP32. I tried with autostart (without pressing any button) and by using enable and boot button, but it is not working. The arduino IDE is displaying a serial data error. I heard that I should desolder the capacitor in parallel with the boot button (C6 100nF). Is this cap causing the issue or there is a schematic mistake ?

OS: Windows 10
Board: Custom (based on ESP32-Devkitc-V4 by Espressif)
IDE: Arduino
USB/UART Bridge: CP2102N-A02-GQFN24R

[image: ESP32 custom board]
[image: ESP32-Devkitc-V4 by Espressif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CP2102N VIO pin is not connected, so it is missing a supply voltage for IO pins and thus can't work.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is working perfectly !!